# How to lazy load child objects using RESTAdapter and Ember Data 1.0.0 beta 3

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The example I have found online show something as follows:

```
Flashcards.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),

  flashGroups: DS.hasMany('flashGroup', {async: true})
});

Flashcards.FlashGroup = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),

  subject: DS.belongsTo('subject')
});
```

And then format JSON as follows:

```
{"subject": {"id": 1, "name": "foo", "links": {"flash_groups": "/subjects/1/flash_groups"}}}
```

When I try sumSubject.get('flashGroups'), nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a bug where `links` keys are not camelized. Try to return the following JSON:

```
{"subject": {"id": 1, "name": "foo", "links": {"flashGroups": "/subjects/1/flash_groups"}}}
```

(use `flashGroups` instead of `flash_groups`)